# XPATH Grab Last Node in Series

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="breadcrumb-container">    
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li style="" class=""><a href="/some-link1">Text 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/some-link2">Text 2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/some-link3">Text 3</a></li>
    <li class="">Some Heading Text</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

I am trying to grab the last piece of text which is `Text 3`

```
//div[@class='breadcrumb-container']/ul/li/a[last()]
```

This seems to grab all three pieces of text for some reason. I need to specifically grab the last `li` class that has an a `href` in it.

I have also tried `AND`but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in brackets and then use last

```
(//div[@class='breadcrumb-container']/ul/li/a)[last()]
```

#If you want to get Text out of it then just add `//text()` at the end

#If you have some `a` without `href` and you want to exclude them

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  ...
  <li class=""><a href="/some-link3">Text 3</a></li>
  <li class=""><a>Without href 1</a></li>
  <li class=""><a>Without href 2</a></li>
  <li class="">Some Heading Text</li>
</ul>
```

then just add `a[@href]`

```
(//div[@class='breadcrumb-container']/ul/li/a[@href])[last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with **xpath-descendant**

```
(//div[@class='breadcrumb-container']//descendant::a)[last()]
```